# Feeds import - Skip importing item based on some condition

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

I am making API call to import data into Drupal. The API provides 2 filters by which I can get the data. Now I want to apply additional filter on the returned data and only save data which validate the third filter. 
E.g. 
The API - http://example.com/users?country=US&state=NY
Requirement - I want to import users data into Drupal only if users age is above 18 (And from US-NYC).

Now the API do not have age filter, but it provides age in the response. How can I write a code to ask feed importer to skip import if age is below 18.

Hope I am clear asking this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using hook_feeds_presave to check the data prior to it being saved.

```
function mymodule_feeds_presave(FeedsSource $source, $entity, $item) {

  // check that this is fired only for the importer being used
  if($source->importer->id=='my_user_importer'){

    // check that the age is over 18
    if($item['age'] < '18'){
      $entity->feeds_item->skip = TRUE;
      drupal_set_message(t("Skipping user who's age is below 18", 'warning');
    }
  }
}
```